# Making an image button in Unity 2019.3.12f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

When I try to assign a source image to a Unity.UI button it always ends up blurry/distorted on the edges. I played with the resolution and some settings also tried with other images but it doesn't make a difference. the images I tried were png files and had transparent backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Unity applies a bilinear filter to textures that blur them slightly. This is often good if you have a high-resolution image since it removes hard edges. However, if you have a low-resolution image (e.g. pixel art) you might not want this. To disable it, click on the image in the project tab and change `Filter Mode` to `Point (no filter)` in the inspector.

This is how an image can look with the `Bilinear` filter mode:

[image: Image with bilinear filter mode]

Compared to how it looks with the `Point` filter mode:

[image: Image with point filter mode]